# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'settings.tableClass')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I've use the yiiGridView before with the checkbox and is working fine, but when I try to do it on a renderPartial page, it keep getting this error.
Here is my view.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width: 80em">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo Yii::t('webposModule.strings','cusRelation.emailTemplate')?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body clearfix" style="width: 80em; overflow-y: auto; max-height: 20%">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="form-group">
                <i><?php echo Yii::t('webposModule.strings','cusRelation.birthdayPackage.chooseList'); ?></i>
                <?php
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
                    'id' => 'oc-list-email-template',
                    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
                    'summaryText' =>'',
                    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'overflow-y: auto; max-height: 40%'),
                    'emptyText' => Yii::t ('webposModule.strings', 'cusRelation.birthdayPackage.promoList.empty'),
                    'columns' => array(
                        array('name'=> 'emailid',
                            'value'=>'$data["id"]',
                            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none;'),
                            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none;'),
                            'filterHtmlOptions'=>array('style' => 'display:none;'),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'header' => '',
                            'id' => 'chkbox',
                            'name' => 'checkBox',
                            'selectableRows' => 2,
                            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'header'=> Yii::t('webposModule.strings','cusRelation.templateName'),
                            'name'=> 'templateName',
                            'value'=>'$data["template_name"]',
                            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=> 'cursor: pointer'),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'header'=> Yii::t('webposModule.strings','cusRelation.subject'),
                            'name'=> 'subject',
                            'value'=>'$data["subject"]',
                            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=> 'cursor: pointer'),
                        ),
                    ),
                ));
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php echo CHtml::button(Yii::t ('webposModule.strings', 'cusRelation.apply'), array('id'=>'apply-email-template','class'=>'btn btn-default btn-top-rv oc-apply-email-template btn-block','data-dismiss'=>'modal')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript.

```
$(document).on('click', '.oc-apply-email-template', function (event) {
    var memid = <?php echo Octopus::catchRequest('memid')?>;
    var selectedCheckbox = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked('oc-list-email-template', 'chkbox');
    console.log(selectedCheckbox);
})
```

It keep showing this error as shown in the title, when I click on this error, it bring me to this line located in jquery.yiigridview.js

```
this.find('.' + settings.tableClass).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').children('input[name="' + column_id + '"]').each(function (i) {
```

Comment: the first thing I notice, does `Octopus::catchRequest('memid')` return a properly [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)d string?

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure that you're not supposed to call `$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked` yourself, not like that. Rather something along the lines of `$(gridID).yiiGridView('getChecked', columnID)`